# MySQL prepared statement nvarchar

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1054

I have a prepared statement which should update an field.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `update_table` (in id INT, in col nvarchar(11), in val nvarchar(10))
BEGIN
SET @sql = concat('UPDATE table SET ', col, ' = ', val , ' WHERE id = ', id);
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END
```

If I call the procedure with a string containing a hyphen (e.g. A-B)

> CALL update_table(1, 'reg', 'A-B');

I get

> Error 1054: Unknown column 'A' in 'field list'

Can you please assist in solving the issue?

Edit: I just figuered out the hyphen is not the cause of error. If I try to update with 'AB', the same error comes up.
The field to be updated is nvarchar as well with the same field length.

Comment: what do the table and the actual call to the procedure look like ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com), basically. Your sproc generated this sql:

```
UPDATE ... WHERE reg = A-B
```

Note the lack of quotes around `A-B`. You're not storing the string `A-B` in the `reg` field. You're doing mathematical subtraction: `reg = A minus B`, and neither `A` nor `B` are fields that exist in your table.

At BARE minimum you'd need:

```
SET @sql = concat('UPDATE table SET ', col, ' = "', val , '" WHERE id = ', id);
                                                ^----------^
```

so you're generating

```
UPDATE ... reg = "A-B"
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your promt input. I'm aware of the sql injection problem and trying to avoid it by using a small php script which uses 'mysqli_real_escape_string' and 'strip_tags' to avoid sql injection

Comment: Also, that actually is not how you are supposed to use a prepared statement.